# How do I set a callback function parameter like 'data' in the "jQuery.ajax({ success : function(data)"?

Tags: javascript, callback

I am wondering how to set the first parameter of a callback function to what I want, the same way jquery does in the success callback or the complete callback

I want to do this:

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data)
  }
});
```

from what I understand this is as close as I can get to what I want

```
function test(text) {
  this.text = text
  this.success = function(this.text) { }
}

var a = new test('King Kong')
a.success = function(k){
  alert(k)
}
```

and I want the alert to say "King Kong"

Comment: You want this to happen in your object?  is the .ajax just an example?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of accepting a callback in your constructor function and then calling it later in response to some trigger. In the below, the trigger is someone calling the `trigger` function, but it can be anything you want:

```
function Test(text, callback) {

  this.text = text;
  this.success = callback;
}

Test.prototype.trigger = function() {
    // Call the success callback, passing in the text
    this.success(this.text);
};

var a = new Test('King Kong', function(k) {
    alert(k);
});

a.trigger();
```

*(I've made `Test` initially-capped there. That's the convention for constructor functions, which you are of course free to ignore.)*

The key, fundamental thing to understand is that functions are just objects like anything else. You can pass references to them around, etc. To *call* a function, you just access whatever variable you have the function reference stored in and add parentheses (optionally with the function's arguments in the parentheses).

Consequently, all of the following call the `foo` function and trigger the alert:

```
function foo(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}

var f = foo;   // No parens, just getting the function reference, not calling it
f("Hi there"); // Now we're calling it
var a = {};
a.nifty = f;
a.nifty("Hi again");

function bar(func) {
    func("Hello for the third time");
}
bar(foo);     // Passing a reference to `foo` into the `bar` function, which will call it
```

---

**Advanced**: Now, one thing that jQuery does is that it calls the callback with the `this` value set to something specific (usually the DOM element related to the call). That will happen any time you call a function via an object property:

```
var a = {name: "Fred"};
a.func = function() {
    alert(this.name);
};
a.func(); // alerts "Fred"
```

...but that's not the only way you can do it; there's also the `call` and `apply` functions on the function object itself:

```
var a = {name: "Fred"};
function func() {
    alert(this.name);
}
func.call(a); // alerts "Fred"
```

There, the function isn't assigned to any of `a`'s properties, but we've called the function using `call`, which accepts the value for `this` as its first argument. Call also passes on any further arguments to the function you're calling:

```
function func(msg1, msg2) {
   alert(this.name + " says " + msg1 + " and " + msg2);
}
var a = {name: "Fred"};
func.call(a, "one", "two"); // alerts "Fred says one and two"
```

`apply` does exactly the same thing, but it accepts the arguments to pass on to the underlying function as an array instead of as discrete arguments:

```
function func(msg1, msg2) {
   alert(this.name + " says " + msg1 + " and " + msg2);
}
var a = {name: "Fred"};
func.apply(a, ["one", "two"]); // alerts "Fred says one and two"
//            ^------------^----- note these args are now an array
```

More reading: [***Mythical Methods***](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was looking for, it was this

```
function Test(data) 
  {
    data.success(data.text)
  }

  var a = new Test({
    text : 'DATA',
    success : function(k) {
      alert(k)
    }
  })
```

or

```
 function Test() 
  {
    this.setText = function(k) {
      this.text = k
    }
    this.setCall = function(k) {
      this.call = k
      this.call(this.text)
    }
  }

  var a = new Test
  a.setText('DATA')

  a.setCall(function(k) {
    alert(k)
  })
```

both alert "DATA"